# What does this line do in the post_save signal?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm a newbie and learning Django 1.8 from the Udemy Django series. On the tutorial the instructor has tried to implement post_save signal and to relate each product variations to its product. For example product is "SmartPhone" and product variations are "samsung galaxy S6,iPhone 6s,Nexus 6P,HTC One A9 etc". Although the code works I'm confused what does  below line of code do inside the function.

```
def product_saved_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    variations = product.variation_set.all() <==where did variation_set.all() came from?
```

Below is the complete models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.

class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)


class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self.db)

    def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_queryset().active()


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = ProductManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
        # OR use this- return "/product/%s"%(self.pk)


class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)  ##this means each Variation is related to single product
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  # default=-1 means unlimited

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_price(self):
        if self.sale_price is not None:
            return self.sale_price
        else:
            return self.price

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.product.get_absolute_url()


# for post save receiver


def product_saved_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    # sender=modelclass, instance=actual instance being saved,created=boolean true if record was created
    product = instance
    variations = product.variation_set.all()
    if variations.count() == 0:
        new_var = Variation()
        new_var.product = product
        new_var.title = "Default"
        new_var.price = product.price
        new_var.save()

post_save.connect(product_saved_receiver, sender=Product)



#slugify
def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    title = instance.product.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    file_extension = filename.split(".")[1]
    # or  basename,file_extension = filename.split(".")
    new_filename = "%s.%s" %(instance.id,file_extension)
    return "products/%s/%s" %(slug, filename)

# above function changed for slugfying

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to) #image will be uploaded to media/mediaroot/products

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.title

###
```

Comment: [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a foreign key from

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

That allows multiple variations to be linked to one product. For any individual `variation`, you can access the related product with `variation.product`.

Django also creates an 'accessor' for the other side of the relationship, so you can access the variations related to a product. By default, it uses the name of the model in lowercase, with `_set` appended. The default can be overridden with the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) attribute.

In your case, the line that you asked about,

```
variations = product.variation_set.all()
```

is fetching all of the variations related to `product`. It gives the same result as if you did:

```
variations = Variation.objects.filter(product=product)
```

See the docs on [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) for more information.

Comment: thankyou for shedding the light and time for explanation. i guess in "product.variation_set.all()"  the word "Variation" is all small letters , on the django link you provided..under  *Following relationships “backward”  topic the model class which imported another class as foreign key for example "b.entry_set.all()".

Comment: You're right, the model name is lowercase and then `_set` is added. This follows [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).